# How to handle null pointer exception in vc# using MySQL DataReader?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

When I am running this code:

```
count = mdr.GetInt32("total");
```

mdr is an object of MySQL DataReader

To get the value of total field from my table, if it returns NULL the application stops with a null pointer exception.

Is there any way to catch this exception?

Comment: You don't catch the exception, you avoid provoking it, e.g. `if (!mdr.IsDBNull("total")) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

Since apparently 'null' is a valid (or semi-valid) value for the field "count," you could consider changing count from `int` to the nullable `int?`.

Alternately you could just surround the call with a try {} catch {} block, as so:

```
try
{
  count = mdr.GetInt32("total");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  //Any logic you would like to run if "total" is null.
}
```

Comment: Don't do this.  Ever.  Try catch blocks are not meant to be used as validation.  Doing something like this could cause serious lagging in your program.  Like the comment above, you don't catch the exception, you avoid provoking it.  @Jon Skeet has the correct answer. Can someone please down vote this, I don't have the rep.

Comment: @JSON Well if null isn't actually considered a valid value (thus int should remain int and not the nullable int?), this should A) be rare and B) be an actual exception. If it's invalid and common that implies a rather important issue that needs to be addressed outside the concern of the code. Further just doing an if -> assign, if the DB value is null, leaves the default value of 0 on the "total" property, which is erroneous.

Comment: Please read http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2611/never-use-try-catch-for-input-validation

Comment: @JSON For user input? Absolutely, as that's validating an error with what the user provided that can be communicated back to the user so the user can change what he/she provided, AND errors are frankly quite common. A database shouldn't be that way, and can't modify what its providing you. Apples to oranges. Both are fruit, but there's some pretty fundamental differences between the two.

Comment: For any input not just user input.  Pulling values from a database is input. You think the time lag caused by using try catch blocks cares where the input came from?   Users cannot even enter null values, that is not possible.  A blank textbox still hold a string = "".

Comment: Databases can hold null values and is quite common.

Comment: Considering his question is how to avoid the exception rather than WHY he is getting a null value suggest to me that NULL is a value he expects and may get frequently

Comment: @JSON ...If a null value is common, frequent, and most importantly of all *valid* then my first point of changing int to int? stands, and should be the course forward.

Comment: My point is, and I will repeat one more time for the second year college student trying to teach me about good programming practices, you should never do try/catch for input validation. Yes and null values are definitely valid in a database.  Your other method would be fine.  Jon Skeets would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can catch an exception using [try .. catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) block (see [Nex Terren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1614385/nex-terren) answer).

Another way is to use conditional check as [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) mentioned in the comment to the question:

```
if (!mdr.IsDBNull("total")) { ... }
```

Finally, you can use [?: operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
count = mdr.IsDbNull("total") == null ? 0 : mdr.GetInt32("total");
```